# Whether is or are should be filled here

Tags: word-choice

> There ____ an apple and two bananas on the table.

My kid's teacher said the answer is **is**, but I think it should be **are**. Can someone help me with it here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is/are an apple and two bananas on the table.

You should use "is" in the sentence.

When the first noun in a series of nouns connected with "and" is singular  or non-count, you use a singular  verb after there.

But in case the first noun is plural, you use a plural verb as follows:

There are two bananas and an apple on the table.